# Passing state from child component (class based) to parent (Hooks) in React.js

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, geolocation, submit

I'm new to React and building an app that allows posting an item to server, along the title and the location of this item. I built the parent Post component with Hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Location from "./Location";

const Post = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(null);
 
  const submitHandle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append("title", title);
    uploadData.append("latitude", lat);
    uploadData.append("longitude", lng);
    fetch("URL", {
      method: "POST",
      body: uploadData,
    })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {/* Title form: */}

        <label>
          Title:
          <input
            name="title"
            type="text"
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>

        {/* Geolocation: */}

        <Location
          onChange={(e) => setLat(e.target.value) && setLng(e.target.value)}
        />

        <input type="submit" onSubmit={submitHandle} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

And the child Location component class based:

```
import React from "react";

class Location extends React.Component {
  state = { lat: 0, lng: 0, errorMessage: "" };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Getting user geolocation:
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) =>
        this.setState({
          lat: parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),
          lng: parseFloat(position.coords.longitude),
        }),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        <strong>Latitude:</strong>
        {this.state.lat || "(Loading...)"}
        <strong>Longitude:</strong>
        {this.state.lng || "(Loading...)"}
        <input type="hidden" name="lat" value={this.state.lat} />
        <input type="hidden" name="lng" value={this.state.lng} />
      </p>
    );
  }
}

export default Location;
```

The "lat" and "lng" values show up in the address bar when the form is submitted, but when we tried connecting frontend to server, the values aren't passed. I understand that values cannot be passed from child to parent and I found solutions to work around that issue- but I'm not sure how to do it when my components are built differently. Do I have to refactor one of them or is there a simpler solution to that issue? I would be very grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Having a mix of class based and functional components is fine.

The problem here is that you aren't using your props from the parent component. You are passing an `onChange` function to the child but you aren't using it. Also, you aren't passing the values from the parent component to the child. My approach would look something like this:

The only change you need in the parent:

```js
<Location
   setLat={setLat}
   setLng={setLng}
   latValue={lat}
   lngValue={lng}
/>
```

Child:

```js
import React from "react";

class Location extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            // This is unused but maybe you can set it in the error portion of getCurrentPosition and then conditionally render it
            errorMessage: ""
        };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Getting user geolocation:
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
          this.props.setLng(parseFloat(position.coords.longitude));
          this.props.setLat(parseFloat(position.coords.latitude));
      },
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        <strong>Latitude:</strong>
        {this.props.lat || "(Loading...)"}
        <strong>Longitude:</strong>
        {this.props.lng || "(Loading...)"}
        <input type="hidden" name="lat" value={this.props.lat} />
        <input type="hidden" name="lng" value={this.props.lng} />
      </p>
    );
  }
}

export default Location;
```

They key takeaway is that you can utilize callbacks to set parent component values.